# Read a attribute, locate part of it, change it and store somewhere

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code on my website that I can't edit:

```
<ul class="parent">
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <img src="/105-158/someName.png">
    </a>
  </li>
  <!-- a bunch more of those li's -->
</ul>
```

I want to read all the `src`'s, locate `'105-158'` change it to `'1920-2880'` and store it somewhere for future use. I don't want to change the DOM!

I got this far, but I got it to only work with `console.log`:

```
var imageList = document.querySelectorAll('.parent > li > a > img').forEach(i => console.log(i.src.replace('105-158', '1920-2880')))
```

Then, when I click the respective image set it as the `currentImage`.

Comment: "I do now want to change the DOM!" means what? now = not?

Comment: so set a data attribute?

Answer (score 2):

You said you want to not change the source, but save the new source somewhere so you can reference it. Easiest thing is use data attribute to store it.

```
var imageList = document.querySelectorAll('.parent > li > a > img')
imageList.forEach(img => img.dataset.src = img.src.replace('105-158', '1920-2880'))
console.log(imageList[2].dataset.src)
```

If you really want it as an array use map()

```
var imageList = document.querySelectorAll('.parent > li > a > img')
var srcs = Array.from(imageList).map(img => img.src.replace('105-158', '1920-2880'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's definitely a valid one, but I don't want to store it as a data attribute also. I was thinking more like a array? `imageList = [img1 = '/1920-2880/someName1', img2 = '/1920-2880/someName2']`

Comment: So store it as an array with map() I am not sure why it is a big deal to use a dataset.